# read txt file input and add values to two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
A   B   C  D

2   4   5  6

4   5   3  7

3   6   7  8
```

I want to get `A`, `B`, `C` column values to array(3 x 3) and `D` column to another array(3 x 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np    

# Read the data from a file
with open('data.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Chop of the columns
raw_data = lines[1:]

# Now fetch all the data
data_abc = []
data_d = []

for line in raw_data:
    values = line.split()
    data_abc.append(values[:3])
    data_d.append(values[3])

# Convert to matrix
data_abc = np.asmatrix(data_abc)
data_d = np.asmatrix(data_d)

# Display the result
print('Data A B C:', data_abc)
print('Data D:', data_d)
```

Comment: It's working well though but when i put the file as the in put it says " AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split' "

Comment: Then you need to load the file into memory and loop through all the lines (see the updated code).

Answer (score 0):

simple brute-force method:

```
a33 = [[],[],[]]
a31 = []

with open('dat.txt') as f:
    for ln in f:
        a,b,c,d = ln.split()
        a33[0] += a
        a33[1] += b
        a33[2] += c
        a31 += d

print a33
print a31

[['2', '4', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['5', '3', '7']]
['6', '7', '8']
```